# Is there a good site to hire programmers for little projects?

Tags: hiring, outsourcing

I need to a piece of php code that goes beyond my abilities so I need to hire somebody to do it. It's not really something too long or complex so I wanted to know if there was a straightforward way to post my request and find somebody to do it for a certain amount. Does such a website exists or what's the best alternative? Anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the following sites:

- [oDesk](http://www.odesk.com/)
- [eLance](http://www.elance.com/)
- [scriptlance](http://www.scriptlance.com/)
- [vWorker](http://www.vworker.com/) (originally rent a coder)
- [Rent A Coder](http://www.rent-acoder.com/)
- [Code Monkey For Hire](http://www.codemonkeyforhire.com/)
- [FreeLancer](http://www.freelancer.com/)

I know someone that reasonable success with oDesk.

Answer (score 4):

There's a number of such sites, however, with the experiences that myself and some friends have had as a programmer on these sites, I can't in good conscience recommend any of them.

My suggestion is to get better at what you do: ask questions on StackOverflow if you can't immediately figure it out.

Comment: Ok I'll have it in mind, I'll get somebody I know or keep trying to do it myself

Comment: What's the reason for this?